# Trying to understand how constructors and different parameter types work inside classes in Swift

Tags: swift, class, parameters

New to Swift but have some previous knowledge about C# and Java programming.  Trying to understand how "Constructors" and parameter types work in Swift when creating and instantiating a class.

My problem is below:

```
public class MyClass {
    private var somethingA : String
    private var somethingB : String
    private var somethingC : Int
    private var complexes:[String:[String:Int]] = [String:[String:Int]]();

    init() {
         self.somethingA = "";
         self.somethingB = "";
         self.somethingC = 0;
         self.complexes = [somethingA:[somethingB:somethingC]];

    }

    public func addSomething(somethingAA : String) {

         self.somethingA = somethingAA;
    }

    public func addComplex(somethingAA:  String, complex:(somethingBB:  String,  somethingCC:  Int)) {

         self.somethingA = somethingAA;

         // How do I assign the complex:(somethingBB, somethingCC) parameter to my self variable 'complexes'?
    }

}
```

When I tried doing it like the following, I get the following errors for each line:

```
self.somethingB = somethingBB;     // Use of unresolved identifier 'somethingBB'
self.somethingC = somethingCC;     // Use of unresolved identifier 'somethingCC'
self.complexes = [somethingAA:[somethingBB:somethingCC]];   //use of unresolved identifier 'somethingBB' and 'somethingCC'
```

Comment: Just a note that naming stuff like `somethingB` and `somethingBB` doesn't help people to better understand what you need.

Comment: @Cristik : Agree , name of parameters and variables should be proper, so it would be better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For error inside function `addComplex`, parameter `complex` is tuple, which contains two value named `somethingBB` of type `String` and `somethingCC` of typle `Int`.

So to access value from [tuple](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-tuple) you have to access it with dot notation.

```
self.somethingB = complex.somethingBB
self.somethingC = complex.somethingCC
```

or you can access parameters from tuple using below syntax also :

```
self.somethingB = complex.0
self.somethingC = complex.1
```

To assign value to `complexes` is type of `Dictionary` of key-value pair. Here key is type of `String` and  value is another `Dictionary` of `[String:Int]`. So you have to construct same structure using raw values from function parameters inside function like below.

```
self.complexes = [somethingAA:[somethingBB:somethingCC]]
```

Try this code:

```
public func addComplex(somethingAA:  String, complex:(somethingBB:  String,  somethingCC:  Int)) {

    self.somethingA = somethingAA;
    self.somethingB = complex.somethingBB
    self.somethingC = complex.somethingCC
    self.complexes = [somethingAA:[somethingBB:somethingCC]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the function `addComplex(somethingAA: String, complex:(somethingBB: String,  somethingCC: Int))` takes a [tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) of name `complex` which consist of `String` and `Int`. To assign values from `tuple` to your properties, you need to use `tupleName.propertyName` kind of pattern, using this your addAddComplex function becomes

```
 public func addComplex(somethingAA:  String, complex:(somethingBB:  String,  somethingCC:  Int)) {
      somethingA = somethingAA
      somethingB = complex.somethingBB
      somethingC = complex.somethingCC
      //create a dict with somethingB and somethingC values
      complexes = [somethingAA: [somethingB: somethingC]]
      print(complexes)
 }
```

Now if you call function addComplex like below which will print `["AAA": ["BBB": 10]]`

```
let myClass = MyClass()
myClass.addSomething(somethingAA: "Hellow")
myClass.addComplex(somethingAA: "AAA", complex: (somethingBB: "BBB", somethingCC: 10))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear *how* you want to add the tuple to the `complexes` property. Do you want to add a new entry in the dictionary? Do you want to replace the existing dictionary with the parameter values?

You probably have a misunderstanding of how tuples work. This parameter:

```
complex:(somethingBB:  String,  somethingCC:  Int)
```

Is a parameter called `complex`, with the type of `(somethingBB: String, somethingCC: Int)`. There is not a single parameter called `somethingBB` or `somethingCC`. There *is*, however, `complex.somethingBB` and `complex.somethingCC`. Think of tuples in Swift like `System.Tuple` in C#, but better. That way, you wouldn't mistake `somethingBB` and `somethingCC` as parameters when they are just members of a tuple type.

Now, you should know how to add the tuple into the dictionary. If you want a new entry:

```
complexes[somethingAA] = [complex.somethingBB: complex.somethingCC]
```

If you want to replace the existing entry:

```
complexes = [somethingAA : [complex.somethingBB : complex.somethingCC]]
```

In production code, you should probably not use complex types like `[String: [String: Int]]`, create a struct or class for it.

EDIT:

If you want to append an entry to the *inner* dictionary, you need to check whether there is a value associated with the key `somethingAA` first:

```
if complexes[somethingAA] == nil {
    complexes[somethingAA] = [somethingBB: somethingCC]
} else {
    complexes[somethingAA][somethingBB] = somethingCC
}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer was very put together.  I just had a question:  what happens if I don't want to replace an existing entry but want to append to an existing entry instead?

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are one of Swift's less visible language features. They occupy a small space between Structs and Arrays. In addition, there's no comparable construct in Objective-C (or many other languages).

> A tuple can combine different types into one. Tuples are value types
>   and even though they look like sequences they aren't sequences, as
>   there's no direct way of looping over the contents.

There are different types of tuples:

```
// A simple tuple
let tuple1 = (2, 3)
let tuple2 = ("a", "b", "c")

// A named tuple
let tuple3 = (x: 5, y: 3)

// Different types of contents
let tuple4 = (name: "Carl", age: 78, friends: ["Bonny", "Houdon", "Miki"])
```

The ways in which you can access tuple elements are:

```
// Accessing tuple elements
let tuple5 = (13, 21)
tuple5.0 // 13
tuple5.1 // 21

let tuple6 = (x: 21, y: 33)
tuple6.x // 21
tuple6.y // 33
```

Now coming to your question the **comlpex** parameter is a named tuple In which

```
complex:(somethingBB:  String,  somethingCC:  Int)
```

the first parameter in the tuple is **somethingBB** type of string and **somethingCC** type of Int.

You can simply access somethingBB and somethingCC by doing

```
self.somethingB = complex.somethingBB
self.somethingC = complex.somethingCC
```

or

```
self.somethingB = complex.0
self.somethingC = complex.1
```